# .htaccess редирект средствами mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

На сайте использую ЧПУ. Пример:

```
RewriteRule ^index$ index.php
RewriteRule ^index/$ index.php
```

В итоге, в адресную строку можно легко вводить такой адрес `http://site.ru/index`. Но вот незадача. Как теперь сделать так, чтобы ссылка типа `http://site.ru/index.php` стала недоступной, а доступ ко странице `index.php` мог бы осуществлять только по адресу `http://site.ru/index`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваши два правила легко можно объединить в одно, взяв слеш в квадратные скобки и написав после них знак вопроса - это сделает его "необязательным" символом, который может быть, а может не быть.

По сути вопроса - например, так:

```
RewriteRule ^index[/]?$ index.php [L,E=ACCESS_ALLOWED:1]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_ACCESS_ALLOWED} ^$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [F]
```

Что тут происходит: первая строчка дублирует Ваши правила из вопроса, с той разницей, что при перенаправлении с `index` на `index.php` устанавливает переменную окружения `ACCESS_ALLOWED` со значением 1. Имя переменной можно выбрать произвольно - она не имеет значения для Apache, и нужна нам только в этих правилах.

Во второй и тертьей строчке задаются два условия: "запрошен URI index.php" и "значение переменной окружения `ACCESS_ALLOWED` пусто". В последней строчке запрещается доступ к `index.php`.

Как это работает: при запросе `index` или `index/` происходит перенаправление на `index.php` с установкой переменной `ACCESS_ALLOWED`, равной 1. Условие о пустой переменной `ACCESS_ALLOWED`, соответственно, не срабатывает, и обусловленное этим правило о запрете доступа к `index.php` не выполняется. При запросе же `index.php` напрямую переменная `ACCESS_ALLOWED` оказывается не установленной, условие о её пустоте срабатывает, и обусловленное им правило о запрете доступа к `index.php` выполняется. В итоге по запросу `index` попасть на `index.php` можно, а по "прямому" запросу `index.php` - нет.

Можно, на самом деле, поступить ещё изящнее: вместо запрета доступа "напрямую" к `index.php` просто перебрасывать такие запросы HTTP-редиректом на "рекомендуемый" `index/`, сделать это можно вот так:

```
RewriteRule ^index[/]?$ index.php [L,E=ACCESS_ALLOWED:1]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_ACCESS_ALLOWED} ^$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ index/ [L,R=301]
```

Такая схема с 301-м редиректом полезна, когда у вас на сайте изменились адреса страниц, и есть задача "обучить" новым адресам поисковые системы, но не хочется терять трафик, идущий со старых ссылок на старые адреса.

Comment: Использовал первый вариант с перенаправлением. А как будет выглядеть запись, если мы используем в своей ссылке ещё и GET параметры? Пример: RewriteRule ^test/([a-z0-9]+)? test.php?v1=$1. Стало быть так: RewriteRule ^test[/]([a-z0-9]+)?$ test.php?us=$1 [L,E=ACCESS_ALLOWED:1]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test.php$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_ACCESS_ALLOWED} ^$
RewriteRule ^test.php$ test/ [L,R=301]