# Пути без расширений в URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

Видел, что многие сайты делают следующее: http://example.com/feed - и нет никакого расширения. Я понимаю, что можно скрыть через *.htaccess*, но, если я попытаюсь дописать разные расширения, например, *.php* - http://example.com/feed.php, то выдает 404 not found. Не обязательно *.php*, я имею ввиду многие другие... А на некоторых вообще, так - http://example.com/aZWryG - последнее генерируется рендомно, очень удобно, это я видел в коротких ссылках. Если и там попробовать подбирать расширения, то тоже самое - 404.

Скажите, пожалуйста, как этого добиться? Или как заставить *.htaccess* выдавать ошибку, если дописано расширение?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самый простой способ — полностью перенести роутинг в скрипт, не разводя по несколько скриптов на каждый случай. Вы можете перенаправить абсолютно все запросы через один скрипт, который будет решать, как поступать с запросом дальше, и какой скрипт выполнять.

Если хотите скрыть реальное имя скрипта, то дайте ему какое-нибудь уникальное имя, например `c426ce285ea5448f821146836b6586e4.php`, и сделайте это имя индексным с помощью *.htacceess*:

```
DirectoryIndex c426ce285ea5448f821146836b6586e4.php
```

Как вариант, можете оставить человеческое имя вроде *index.php*, но генерировать ошибку скриптом. Внешне отличий не будет (ну, почти).

Comment: а разве DirectoryIndex не делает просто определенную страницу директория по-умолчанию?? как он мне поможет?

Comment: @maschine В том скрипте, который указан в DirectoryIndex, распарсите Request URI и вызовите нужный вам скрипт. "Если URI начинается с 'feed', выполнить 'feed.php', иначе выполнить 'error.php'." В таком духе.

Answer (score 1):

> Или как заставить .htaccess выдавать ошибку, если дописано расширение?

Как раз такую задачу - перенаправлять запросы произвольного URI (в том числе можно и "без расширения") на `файл.php`, но генерировать ошибку при прямом запросе `файл.php`, обсуждали [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/352814/).