# Как в исходном коде страницы скрыть php расширение в ссылках?

Tags: php, ссылки

Хочу скрыть расширение чтобы видно было только название страницы в ссылке. Какие способы существуют для этих целей?

Comment: Не выводите расширения и все. В чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: См. также по теме вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413709/%d0%9f%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это задается через правила в .htaccess в корне вашего проекта.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Запросы типа /index будут отправлены на /index.php или /car будет перенаправлен на /car.php