# htaccess mod_rewrite запрет на прямой доступ

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Во время написания сайта мне понадобилось сделать чтобы пользователь не видел в строке запроса (url) переменных и т.д. а видел как подпапки (www.example.com/view/1 ..)
это понятно как сделать, и с помощью этого можно ограничить вводимые значения..
вот пример того как я написал переход "programs/view/1" к index.php?navigation=programs&id=1

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^programs/view/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?navigation=programs&id=$1    [NC,L]
```

но как теперь запретить вводить в адресной строке напрямую целевой адрес (index.php?navigation=programs&id=1)
Я спрашиваю про это , потому-что от этого зависит нужно ли проверять переменную id, т.е. вместо "1" можно подставить часть запроса к базе ..

([тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/352814/htaccess-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-mod-rewrite) ранее уже предложили решение, но у меня оно не работает(по этому прошу не ставить как дубликат вопроса ..) - вставлю предложенный там код:

```
RewriteRule ^index[/]?$ index.php [L,E=ACCESS_ALLOWED:1]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_ACCESS_ALLOWED} ^$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [F]
```

мой код, в котором не срабатывает блокировка:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^programs/view/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?navigation=programs&id=$1    [NC,L,E=ACCESS_ALLOWED:1] 
RewriteRule ^programs/ index.php?navigation=programs [NC,E=ACCESS_ALLOWED:1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_ACCESS_ALLOWED} ^$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [F]
```

Comment: Не надо костыли городить, просто проверяйте всё всегда

Comment: @andreymal понятно что можно просто проверить в конечном коде переменную, но всё равно не хочется пускать пользователя "по прямой" ссылке со вводом переменных..